# Run enumerate for all files in directory starting from 40.txt

Tags: python, rename, glob, enumeration, enumerate

I have a folder with several files in txt extension (40.txt, 41.txt, 42.txt...100.txt) I want to run the following code for them.

```
import glob
for i, file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.txt"),42):
...
pipeline.load('txt', f'{i}.txt')
...
pipeline.myfunction('myfunction', '1.png', f'{i}.txt')
...
pipeline.write(f'result{i}.csv')
```

However, when I run it, it performs the operation with 40.txt and stops. How can I change it, so it works with all txt files in directory?

Comment: Be careful: `glob.glob("*.txt")` might put `100.txt` before `40.txt` in the returned list, so your index `i` won't necessarily match the filename.

Comment: "Now i want to apply this code for files starting from 40.txt (40.txt, 41.txt...100.txt)." The `i` values that you get from `enumerate` have **nothing to do with** what `glob.glob` will find. If you want to skip those files, that is a completely different question. Please be *specific* and show an [mre]. Make sure it is possible to see: what happens when you try your existing code? What should happen instead, and **exactly how is that different**?

Answer (score 0):

There is a "starting value" argument for `enumerate()`:

Change your loop line to this:

```
for i, file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.txt"), 40):
```

Comment: This will still match `0.txt`, `1.txt`, etc.  It is unclear if that is the desired result.

Comment: Thank you, that works. Is there a method to avoid stopping this code in case the file is damaged/has wrong format, so the script just skips it and keeps running?

Comment: @lemontree please note that this is **not a discussion forum**. Questions here exist to help build a library, [not to solve the asker's problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478). Please ask separate questions separately.

Comment: Changed it to for i, file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.txt"), 4o). It only worked with 40.txt file and stopped.